# How do I test my website on mobile devices

Tags: web-development, website-design, mobile

I would like to develop my websites with mobile devices in mind.

However as I am new to web development, I'm not exactly sure how I would go about testing my websites on let's say an iPhone, when the website isn't live.

Does anyone know how I would go about testing a website on my local machine on my iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most basic solution is to test that in your browser (chrome/ firefox). These browsers provide you option to set screen resolution and emulate any device.

In Firefox you can bring up developer tools by right clicking on the page and selecting "Inspect Element."  There is then a button to view mobile sizes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go this is from Google it allows you to test your website across every possible device size and orientation

http://g.co/design/resizer

But you will need to host your website unfortunately so for future reference this will be the ideal url to go to.

As for offline testing you can use brackets live view